# Avoiding nested callbacks when using MongooseJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, mongodb, mongoose

I'm diving into the world of nodejs and mongo. I am playing around with a simple app that uses MongooseJS to talk to Mongo. I have been looking at examples and some GitHub projects for references, but the pattern seems very sloppy to me. Is this approach considered normal, or is there a better way?

Here is a sample from the app I am building with my daughter. Those nested callbacks feel like an anti-pattern to me.  Am I wrong? Are there better ways to do it?

```
//userController.js when a new user registers an account is made and a document is cloned that will be their new "pet";

var Pet = require("models/pet.js");
var User = require("models/user.js");

exports.register = function (req, res, next) {
    var user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }

        Pet.findOne({
            "name": "Egg",
            "ownerId": "<<system>>"
        }, function (err, pet) {
            if (err){
                next(err);
                return;
            }
            Pet.clonePetForUser(user._id, pet._id, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    next(err);
                    return;
                }
                res.json({message: 'User created'});
            })
        }); 
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you're right, there are better solutions. For example you could use promises instead of callbacks since mongoose operations can return promises according to the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).

Your example with promises:

```
var Pet = require("models/pet.js");
var User = require("models/user.js");

exports.register = function (req, res, next) {

    var user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    user.save()
        .then(function () {
            return Pet.findOne({
                "name": "Egg",
                "ownerId": "<<system>>"
            });
        })
        .then(function (pet) {
            return Pet.clonePetForUser(user._id, pet._id);
        })
        .then(function () {
            res.json({message: 'User created'});
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
            next(err);
        });

});
```

You can write your own method to return a promise. Instead of:

```
petSchema.statics.clonePetForUser = function (userId, petId, callback) {
     this.find({ }, callback);
};
```

You can write:

```
petSchema.statics.clonePetForUser = function (userId, petId) {
    return this.find({ });
};
```

Comment: ah! This is how I was thinking it should be. I don't know how I missed that mongoosejs had promises. Much cleaner. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is due to asynchronous JavaScript, and this is called [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

You can deal with it through some design patterns, the Zoltan's answer is a really good one (way better than mine). But I'll show you another here based on your original code.

---

## Named callbacks

The main goal here is to reduce the indentations level to improve the code readability by splitting your script into named functions.

```
exports.register = function (req, res, next) {

    var user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });


    user.save(findAndClonePet);



    function findAndClonePet (err) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }

        findPet();
    }



    function findPet () {
        Pet.findOne({
            "name": "Egg",
            "ownerId": "<<system>>"
        }, function (err, pet) {
            if (err){
                next(err);
                return;
            }
            clonePet(pet);
        });
    }



    function clonePet (pet) {
        Pet.clonePetForUser(user._id, pet._id, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json({message: 'User created'});
        });
    }



};
```

Hm ok it's better but at this point it's not "good" enough. We can see this part is not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) :

```
if (err) {
    next(err);
    return;
}
```

Let's try this :

```
exports.register = function (req, res, next) {

    var user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });



    user.save(handleResponse(findAndClonePet));



    function findAndClonePet () {
        findPet();
    }



    function findPet () {
        Pet.findOne({
            "name": "Egg",
            "ownerId": "<<system>>"
        }, handleResponse(function (err, pet) {
            clonePet(pet);
        }));
    }



    function clonePet (pet) {
        Pet.clonePetForUser(user._id, pet._id, handleResponse(function () {
            res.json({message: 'User created'});
        }));
    }



    function handleResponse (callback) {
        return function (err) {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
                return;
            }

            // Forward all arguments to the callback
            callback.apply(null, Array.from(arguments));
        }
    }


};
```

At this point, you can go deeper, getting out the functions outside the register() scope for reusability purpose : You can build a little home made library to use thoses functions in other scripts of your application.

Comment: I think, there's a mistake: the line "function handleResponse (err) {" should be "function handleReponse (callback) {". Otherwise +1 for the detailed explanation.